# Ajax in a Joomla 3.x component's view

Tags: ajax, model-view-controller, joomla

I'm building a Component for Joomla 3.x and I encounter a problem handling an ajax request.
The source is available on Github: [JomCity](https://github.com/briceeeee/jomcity)

My request is made from the `venues` view : `/com_jomcity/site/views/venues/tmpl/default.php`

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    jQuery('#main_search_request').keyup(function() {
      var request_content = jQuery(this).val();
      jQuery.get(
        // Specify the server URL and the $_GET datas to send
        'index.php?option=com_jomcity&task=searchVenues&format=json',
        { search: request_content },
        // The server will respond with some data encoded in JSON
        function(data){
          jQuery('#results').html('');
          for (var i = 0; i < data.venues.length; i++) {
            var venue = data.venues[i];
            console.log(venue);
            jQuery('#results').append(
              '<div class="grid-item">' +
                '<a href="#">' +
                  '<img src="http://placekitten.com/g/80/80" alt="">' +
                  '<div>' +
                    '<div>' +
                      '<h3>'+venue.name+'</h3>' +
                      '<span>* * * * *</span>' +
                    '</div>' +
                    '<div>Short descrption</div>' +
                  '</div>' +
                '</a>' +
              '</div>'
            );
          }
        }
      );
    });
  });
</script>
```

This ajax script communicate with the main controller of the component (site part), so I'm wondering how can I get the values from the model `com_jomcity/site/models/venues.php`.

Is it possible with this code ? Or should I handle the ajax request in the controller of the view (I didn't find how to do that) ?

Comment: where you want to get the value from the model?

Comment: This question/answer may shed some light onto how you want to approach it: https://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/146/what-is-the-proper-way-to-make-an-ajax-call-in-component/2541#2541

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @Torreto and @GDP for your participation.

I finally kept on creating a task in the main controller exchanging with the database directly, so without using any model. I think it should exist a better and cleaner way to code this ajax call, so I'm open to any advice for further improvement.

The code I used, if it can help someone :

In `/com_jomcity/site/views/venues/tmpl/default.php`:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    jQuery('#main_search_request').keyup(function() {
      var request_content = jQuery(this).val();
      jQuery.get(
        // Specify the server URL and the $_GET datas to send
        'index.php?option=com_jomcity&task=searchVenues&format=json',
        { search: request_content },
        // The server will respond with some data encoded in JSON
        function(data){
          // Clean the #result div between two search results
          jQuery('#results').html('');
          // Read and display each objects returned in the json response
          for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            var venue = data[i];
            jQuery('#results').append(
              '<div class="grid-item">' +
                '<a href="#">' +
                  '<img src="http://placekitten.com/g/80/80" alt="">' +
                  '<div>' +
                    '<div>' +
                      '<h3>'+venue.en_name+'</h3>' +
                      '<span>* * * * *</span>' +
                    '</div>' +
                    '<div>Short descrption</div>' +
                  '</div>' +
                '</a>' +
              '</div>'
            );
          }
        }
      );
    });
  });
</script>
```

In `/com_jomcity/site/controller.php`:

```
class JomCityController extends JControllerLegacy
{
    /**
     * Search in all the venues
     * @return string The message to be displayed to the user
     */
    public function searchVenues() {
        if (isset($_GET['search'])) {
            // Get a db connection
            $db = JFactory::getDBO();
            // Create a new query object
            $query = $db->getQuery(true);
            // Select all records from the jomcity_venues_items table
            // Where the name or the description correspond to the user's search keywords
            // Order it by the en_score field
            $query
                ->select('*')
                ->from('#__jomcity_venues_items')
                ->where('`local_name` like "%'.$_GET['search'].'%" OR `en_name` like "%'.$_GET['search'].'%" OR `description` like "%'.$_GET['search'].'%"')
                ->order('en_name ASC');
            // Reset the query using our newly populated query object
            $db->setQuery((string)$query);
            // Load the results as a list of stdClass objects.
            $this->venues = $db->loadObjectList();
        }
        echo json_encode($this->venues);
    }
}
```